# Remove duplicates across django query sets

Tags: python, django

I have the following django queries:

```
AUSTF = TSF.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user).values('FKToT__dNm').distinct()
AUSTU = TSU.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user).values('FKToT__dNm').distinct()
AUSTJS = JSP.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user).values('FKToT__dNm').distinct()
```

This produces **output** that has the same values returned like:

```
123.456.789
website.com
123.456.789
website.com
```

I want to take all `three objects`, and remove any duplicates before outputting in my template. The `distinct()` method does this for single object, but not for all objects when outputted in a template.

I thought appending these three objects to a tuple might work, but that hasnt worked out.

Can someone help? Thanks

---

**what i was thinking**

```
ScannedT = set(AUsersScannedTldsForms,AUsersScannedTldsUrls,AUsersScannedTldsJS)
```

**Output to template**

```
{% if ScannedT %}
        {% for s in ScannedT %}
        <li><span>{{ s.FKToTld__dNm }}</li>         
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
wah
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can't you just use python built-in `set(AUSTF,AUSTU,AUSTJS)`?

Comment: @NarūnasK - the question is how to output to a template by doing that? Would **Output to template** work? if not, how to do this?

Comment: Clarify what do you mean? You can simply add the output from the `set` into the context and use it in the template whichever way you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to lists, then put into a set, which would eliminate duplicates.

```
AUSTF = TSF.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user).values('FKToT__dNm').distinct()
AUSTU = TSU.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user).values('FKToT__dNm').distinct()
AUSTJS = JSP.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user).values('FKToT__dNm').distinct()

# convert to 3 lists
austf_list = list(AUSTF.values_list('FKToT__dNm', flat=True))
austu_list = list(AUSTU.values_list('FKToT__dNm', flat=True))
austjs_list = list(AUSTJS.values_list('FKToT__dNm', flat=True))

# combine all 3 lists, then convert to a set (which eliminates duplicates)
ScannedT = set(austf_list + austu_list + austjs_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your distinct is on a different model, you could just start from that model rather than going on all 3 models. I'm guessing you've obfuscated your model/field names a bit, but I would think:

```
T.objects.filter(FKtoUser=request.user).values('dNm').distinct()
```

would accomplish this. Unless there's a deeper reason I'm missing on why you want to start from the other 3 models.

Comment: Well, this is already being done slightly. The thing is the `3` objects are actually performing queries against 3 different tables. It IS distinct() on all three. But each one can show the same thing over and over, even though its three separate queries (data can the same) when all three querysets are run. so in the template i want to make sure the output is distinct amongst all three

Comment: I must not be properly following your intention. If you're just wanting to show all distinct values for dNm, then you don't need to query all 3 models. Just the T model.

Comment: Well that filter is right, but the three querysets above perform other operations. essentially what im trying to do is take results of `AUSTF` , `AUSTU` , `AUSTJS` and remove the duplicates from them, before outputting them, because currently its printed out the same things for e.g. `AUSTF` and `AUSTU` for example that is shown above in **output**

Comment: OK, but remove what duplicates? If one AUSTU object has the same dNm value as another AUSTJS object, those aren't duplicate objects, though they have the same value for that field.

Perhaps if you showed your template/view logic, I'd understand better?

Comment: I didnt mean remove duplicate objects (as that probably wouldnt ever happen) but remove duplicate object values.  Ill show you what i was thinking above. see **what i was thinking** is that valid?

Comment: I think I see a bit better. You'd likely want to use a set call after converting to a list of values. This should work. You'd likely assign this to a variable then pass it to your view context as a separate key.

set(list(AUSTF.values_list('FKToT__dNm')) + list(AUSTU.value_list('FKToT__dNm')) + list(AUSTJS.values_list('FKToT__dNm')))

Comment: can u show that in an answer? Im not completely following\